# RichTextBox create an empty file

Tags: vb.net, save, richtextbox

I'm trying to save a report file to disk by using a RichTextBox but I'm getting an empty file.

```
ReportRtb.Text = Report & Chr(9) & Source
ReportRtb.SaveFile(FullReportPath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
This Function is called from a Thread, Can be related?

Comment: There's not nearly enough code here to tell you anything meaningful

Comment: @AFriend The other part of the Function is to create the file name path. Do you need that?

Comment: Well we need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which should include how you generate `FullReportPath` as well as what `Report`  and `Source` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this problem is most definitely related to the second thread you use, since you cannot set the Text of a RichTextBox (or any other control on a form) from any other thread but the one it was created from.

Try using the following code.

```
ReportRtb.Invoke(Sub
    ReportRtb.Text = Report & Chr(9) & Source
    ReportRtb.SaveFile(FullReportPath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
End Sub)
```

With the `Invoke(...)` statement, you can call a lambda (or a delegate sub, but a lambda is easier here) from the thread the control was created on, so this will set the text properly and then write it to the file.

If this does not fix the issue, then please check the content of your `Report` and `Source` variables with `Console.WriteLine(...)` or any other logging / debugging output tool.

If this also does not work, check (with a breakpoint) if the function gets called at all, and if so, where does the code stop to work.

If all of this fails, consider implementing your own saving code, since you only use the RichTextBox to write Plain Text. This could be done much more efficient and quicker using the following code:

```
 Dim sw As New StreamWriter(FullReportPath)
 sw.Write(Report & Chr(9) & Source)
 sw.Close() 'Never forget that because if you forget it, the file won't be written, too
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The RTB is not visible, I mean is not on the GUI.I create it inside the Function that is only called by the thread. Also I tryed by calling the function from a Button on the GUI and get the same result. I check the RTB.Text property and seems to be ok.

Comment: Have you tried the breakpoint to see the contents of your variables and if they are correct? Also try the StreamWriter solution instead of the RichTextBox, since the RichTextBox was not designed to function without a GUI and it should be faster and more efficient as well. Ok, I now saw the comment that StreamWriter worked. May I ask you to accept my Answer if it worked for you then?